# Timeout NodeJS Express HTTPS not changeable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, https

I wish to set a timeout, but it is only possible with the HTTP server.

My Code:

```
if (options.web_server_encryption === true) {
    if (options.dev == 0) {
        var httpserver = http.createServer(greenlock.middleware(function (req, res) {
            try {
                res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url})
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            res.end()
        })).listen(options.http_port, function () {
            logger.info(stringbuilder.ldmb("httpstart", options));
        });
        httpserver.timeout = 5000;
        optionsdevcsfs = greenlock.httpsOptions;
    } else {
        var httpserver = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            try {
                res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url})
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            res.end()
        }).listen(options.http_port, function () {
            logger.info(stringbuilder.ldmb("httpstart", options));
        });
        httpserver.timeout = 5000;
        optionsdevcsfs = {key: options.key, cert: options.cert};
    }

    var httpsserver = https.createServer(optionsdevcsfs, app).listen(options.https_port, function () {
        logger.info(stringbuilder.ldmb("httpsstart", options));
    });
    httpsserver.timeout = 5000;
} else if (options.web_server_encryption === false) {
    app.listen(options.http_port, function () {
        logger.info(stringbuilder.ldmb("httpstart", options));
    });
} else {
    logger.error(stringbuilder.ldmb("httpnotstart"));
}

if (options.wse_server_encryption === true) {
    var server = https.createServer(optionsdevcsfs, wse).listen(options.wse_port, function () {
        logger.info(stringbuilder.ldmb("wssstart", options)); //wss
        wseinit();
    });
    server.timeout = 5000;
} else if (options.wse_server_encryption === false) {
    var server = http.createServer(wse).listen(options.wse_port, function () {
        logger.info(stringbuilder.ldmb("wssstart", options)); //ws
        wseinit();
    });
    server.timeout = 5000;
} else {
    logger.error(stringbuilder.ldmb("wssnotstart"));
}
```

I test it with the command:

```
time nc test.trackhe.de 443
```

I have on port 80 my 5 seconds and on the other port a 2 minutes timeout – I guess the default. I try to use the *env.production* bit, it has no effect.

Comment: must be a bug then, because https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_server_timeout